# How to change keyboard of facebook using rest api in iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-rest-api

I have used Rest API facebook in my code and I want to change the default keyboard of Facebook.  How can I change it?

Comment: what do you mean by default keyboard?

Comment: do you mean the login screen?

Comment: @Aravinhanarvi: yes i want to change keyboard appeared at time of login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBConnect uses UIWebView to load the pages from web. Those form elements are not created from the code. So you can not have the access to those methods. so you cant able to change the login screen.